# How to enable Access-Control-Allow-Origin (CORS) to get a video of a local pc client from web

Tags: .net, cors, html5-video

I am trying to load a mp4 file into my website. I am designed a web app which could load video previously stored in some devices that I am going to store. Here is my video tag:

```
<video width="320" height="240" controls="true">
    <source src="file:///E:/Videos/videos%20telejampiq/ALIMENTACIÓN%20AVANCE.mp4" 
            type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

But I receive a message in chome inspector: 
[screenshot of message](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NvCyc.png)

Please help me to solve this.

Answer (score 0):

You do not suposed to load nothing from this src starting with file:///E as you shown

```
<source src="file:///E:/Videos/videos%20telejampiq/ALIMENTACIÓN%20AVANCE.mp4" 
            type="video/mp4">
```

because of the fact that src will stand for a Http Request, and this is not the case in wich you are using file:/// for loading purposes.

try to put this mp4 file inside some of your localhost directories
( from where you load your index.html for example inside a folder called Videos for example)

```
<source src="/Videos/ALIMENTACIÓN%20AVANCE.mp4" 
            type="video/mp4">
```

hope this help you.

Comment: I need to load this video from pc clients,and not from the server (or localhost). I will store this video in E:/Videos/videos%20telejampiq/ALIMENTACIÓN%20AVANCE.mp4 (I have C: and E: ). Thats why I do file:// ...

Comment: I ve posted another answer giving you an option.
in my sample below i am suggesting a python script, but you can also use any kind of language that does the same, eg: nodejs, c#.core and many others

Answer (score 0):

In this case Anargu, you should serve then as static files.

if they have python installed in their machines, you can use the script below, running on the same directory as the video files are

```
import SimpleHTTPServer
import SocketServer
PORT = 8123
Handler = SimpleHTTPServer.SimpleHTTPRequestHandler
httpd = SocketServer.TCPServer(("", PORT), Handler)
print "serving at port", PORT
httpd.serve_forever()
```

and so you can serve then as http://localhost:8123/filename.mp4
in each client machine.